# How to add and remove Textboxes using javascript and then send the data to php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How to create a dynamical add/remove textboxs AND send all the data to PHP? Making a dynamic add and remove is fine, but how do I store it in PHP?

The number of textboxes will vary, so how do I store all of them separately in php?

Comment: there are multiple (broad) questions and no code, please make a start yourself and come back when you need help.

Comment: yes, this is not the place to get ready-to-use code, you have to take start, we will only remove roadblocks in your way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JQuery, and PHP

Here my complete [worked example](https://www.iranthajayasekara.com/blog/jquery-dynamic-table-row-inserter.html). codes are available there.